# Using SearchCriteria and FIlterBuilders is it possible to have a nested AND condition inside ORs?

Tags: magento2, filter, search-criteria

So I know how to create AND condition using the addFilter and how to add OR conditions using FilterBuilder however if I wanted to do do a search like (only using searchCriteria, no direct collection work).

WHERE (email = '12345@email.com' AND status = 'pending') OR (status = 'complete' AND is_virtual = 1)

Is there a nice simple way to do this ?